# Proof of existence of Schauder basis for $L^p(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

There are a statements around, see [[Brezis 2011](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7/page/1), p. 146], like

> All classical (separable) Banach spaces used in analysis have a Schauder basis .

I was wondering where to find a proof confirming this statement for $L^p(\Omega)$ with a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$, $d\in\{2,3\}$, and with $1<p<\infty$.

In the book [*Bases in Banach Spaces*](http://books.google.de/books/about/Bases_in_Banach_spaces.html?id=nYUQAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Singer, where also Brèzis references to, there is a proof for $L^p([0,1])$. Maybe, I just miss how to simply extend the arguments to higher dimensions.

Comment: Jan do you have an electronic version of Singer's book? I was unable to find it neither in Ineternet nor in Libraries. Could you send me via e-mail chapter 17 about extended unconditional bases?

Comment: Sure, if you let me know your address... On my webpage you can find my email...

Comment: thank you! I've send the letter

Comment: @Norbert [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Banach-Spaces-Grundlehren-mathematischen-Wissenschaften/dp/3642516351/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1377167403&sr=8-3&keywords=bases+in+banach+spaces) has a used copy for sale. (I'd like to find a copy of volume 2.)

Comment: @Norbert Oh, the chapter on extended bases is in Volume 2, not 1.

Comment: @DavidMitra take look at [this](http://bookfi.org/s/?q=Bases+in+Banach+spaces+I&t=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can easily construct measurable positive $\rho:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\int_\Omega\rho d\lambda_n=1$. Then consider a non-atomic measure $\nu=\rho^{1/p}d\lambda_n$ and its normalization $\mu=\nu(\Omega)^{-1}\nu$, then we have an isomorphism
$$
I_1:L_p(\Omega,\lambda_n)\to L_p(\Omega,\mu):f\mapsto \rho^{-1/p}\cdot f
$$
Thus $L_p(\Omega,\lambda_n)\cong L_p(\Omega,\mu)$ for some non-atomic probability measure $\mu$.

For any Polish space $K$ and non-atomic probability measure there exist measure-preserving Borel isomorphism $\sigma:\Omega\to[0,1]$ which indices isometric isomorphism
$$
I_2:L_p(\Omega,\mu)\to L_p([0,1],\lambda_1):f\mapsto f\circ\sigma
$$

The space $L_p([0,1],\lambda_1)$ for $p<\infty$ have a basis, for examplee the Haar system.

Thus we conclude $L_p(\Omega,\lambda_n)$ also have a basis.

Comment: I was wondering, if $\int_\Omega\rho d\lambda_n=1$ then why is $\mu=\rho^{1/p}d\lambda_n$ a probability measure?

Comment: @alpastor thanks for pointing out this error. I've have fixed it and hope now the proof is ok.